# E-signature api that doesn't require uploading documents

Tags: api, signature

I am trying to find an api, that enables me to sign documents using Xamarin app. All the apis that I see online asks me to upload the document on their servers. For example, docusign allows me to upload document to a server, and then provide REST services, or Webhooks to access them in the app.

Problem is I can't upload documents anywhere or rather can never get approval to upload them online. So, other than creating my own implementation of e-signature, I will have to find an api, which can work without any document upload.

Is there an api that can do it? Basically if I send the image of signature and document id to it, it can create a e-signature based on that? Or maybe an api that allows access the way we access gallery or contacts in Android or how third party payment system works?

Comment: To be clear, do you mean a [cryptographic signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature), or an image of a handwritten signature?

Comment: I mean a handwritten signature, like used at amazon delivery.

Comment: So, rather than an API, could you use a program or library for PDF manipulation, such as pdftk, to overlay a signature image onto the document?

Comment: But that will not be legally binding. Otherwise, I was planning on just that.

Comment: I don't understand how using a program running on somebody else's computer (via an Internet API) would make the signature legally binding, whereas running the program on your own computer wouldn't. Perhaps you should be talking to https://law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There are some specific certification agencies that provide legally binding signatures. API like docusign uses those certifications to provide legal binding. If I create an api myself, it requires that certification to become legal. Problem is that I can't use the docusign api without asking user to sign in to a different app altogether. If there is a way to implement it better, I can't find a tutorial to do so.